# What happens if the impulse of a collision results in the change in velocity being greater than the speed of sound?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, waves

It is my understanding that impulse travels through materials at the speed of sound through that material (i.e. impulse through steel travels through the steel at ~5000 m/s which is the speed of sound through steel). So lets say we have a collision between 2 objects named A and B. Object B is a solid sphere of some material with a speed of sound of ~5000 m/s, a mass of 1 kg, and a velocity of 0 m/s. Object A is an identical sphere but is travelling at lets say 10,000 m/s. Object A collides with Object B and Object A transfers all of it's momentum to Object B. This would mean that Object B has had an impulse that resulted in Object B travelling faster than impulses can travel through Object B (being that impulses can only travel at the speed of sound).

I cannot really comprehend how such a collision would play out in all honesty. I'm leaning towards the idea that this scenario is just not possible for some variety of reasons but I can't really work out what those reasons are so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can imagine in your example there will be some permanent deformation of the object, the form of which will depend on factors which you have not mention, eg masses, shapes and materials of objects.

The speed of sound is in effect the speed of communication between different parts of the object so it will take time for the information that there is a collision between the two objects to reach the parts of the object remote from the initial collision, a shock wave will be produced.

The video [Balloon Bullet Time - The Slow Mo Guys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNcYm6WjbWI) shows two objects (bullet and balloon) colliding.
You can see a ripple on the third balloon surface in the second experiment after the bullet has hit it.